# Подсветка активного пункта навигации

Tags: php

Есть такой нехитрый код, он обеспечивает подсветку активного пункта навигации:

```
<?php 
    $file = 'xml/navigation.xml';
    $navigation = simplexml_load_file($file);   

    foreach($navigation->item as $item) {
        $active = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $item['id']) !== false ? ' class="active"' : '';
        echo '<li class="item"><a'. $active . ' href="' . $item['id'] . '">' . $item['title'] . '</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

Например, site.org/main, site.org/about и т. п. Но, есть ссылки такого плана: site.org/articles?page=2, site.org/articles?page=5 и т. д. Такую глубину (после site.org/articles), скрипт не берёт.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать для реализации?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант сравнивать `url_path`

```
$file = 'xml/navigation.xml';
$navigation = simplexml_load_file($file);    

foreach($navigation->item as $item) {
    $pathRequest = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $pathItem = parse_url($item['id'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $active = ($pathRequest == $pathItem) !== false ? ' class="active"' : '';
    echo '<li class="item"><a'. $active . ' href="' . $item['id'] . '">' . $item['title'] . '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё прекрасно работает!